# How to adjust windows/icon/font size on raspbian desktop using command line?

Tags: debian, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I have a PiTFT with 320x240 screen size running raspbian desktop on raspberry pi. I would like to resize the whole desktop, make the windows + icons + fonts sizes smaller so it may better fit the screen.

Is there a way to achieve this via terminal (command line)?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to boot into the terminal is to log in with root credentials and enter the following command:

`startx -- -dpi 60`

This is instead of starting the X server

Otherwise, if you have reached desktop , switch to console by <kbd>Ctl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> This will resize the screen into a usable size .

However this is only a workaround and I'm trying to find some really good solution instead of this.

Comment: Tried this before, it can only resize the screen size, but not everything else in it. What really needed is resize the whole thing. Even when I manually lower font-size and icon size, it's too big to fit into small screen.